# EL method with parameter

Tags: jsf, el

I have an entity which i display and modify in an xhtml page. This entity has a getter returned a joined entity using a getter with a parameter (the language):

```
    public JoinedEntity getJoinedEntity(Locale locale){
      for(JoinedEntity je: joinedEntities)
         if(je.getLocale().equals(locale)
            return je;
    }
```

my xhtml cointains the following code:

```
    <h:inputText value="#{myBean.myEntity.getJoinedEntity(localeBean.locale).mytext}"/>
```

There is no problem if i only display this entity but when i try to save the modified JoinedEntity (using TextInputs), i receive an EL exception telling me that there is no getJoinedEntity argument in my Entity.

Is it a possibility to create such a setter:

```
    public void setJoinedEntity(Locale locale, JoinedEntity je){
       ...
    }
```

Is there another way to solve that?

Comment: Why don't you just have field joinedEntity in your Backing bean and instantiate it in some postconstruct method instead of doing that in getter method?

Comment: Because i have a datatable of joinedentities which come from another Entity. I would like to be able to save this other Entity without having to change everything or to save every JoineEntity one by one. And the exception comes from EL. Is it a possibility to create such a setter: setJoinedEntity(Locale locale, JoineEntity je) ?

Comment: Please provide xhtml for getting a better picture of problem

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem. I deleted my getter and used a map as follow:

```
    <h:inputText value="#{myBean.joinedEntities[localeBean.locale].myText}">


    public Map<Locale,JoinedEntity> getJoinedEntities(){
     return joinedEntities;
    }

    public void setJoinedEntities(Map<Locale,JoinedEntity> joinedEntities){
      this.joinedEntities = joinedEntities;
    }
```

Updating the map works then fine.